# How to get the best matching result from the below table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID  | Company  | Type  
--- | -------- | ----  
1   | *        |   *   
2   | CMP1     |   *   
3   | CMP1     |  TYP1
4   | *        |  TYP1
5   | *        |  TYP2
6   | CMP1     |  TYP2
```

(Here Company and Type together makes the Primary Key.)

I have to get the exact match from this table. My different inputs are

```
Company  | Type  |  OutPut
-----    | ----- |  -------
CMP1     | TYP1  |   3
CMP2     | TYP2  |   5
CMP5     | TYP5  |   1
```

If the company is matching with any record get that one otherwise look for the * value.
How do you get this ?

(Currently I did looping each fields and assign a score by best matches, and after that I am getting the top 1 by score value.) Is there any simple way ?

Comment: There seems to be a case missing in your example. What happens if there is one row with an exact match on Company  and wildcard match on type and another  with an exact match on type and wildcard match on company? Which would be regarded as the "best match"?

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the comment, In my case I prefer the Company one

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `outer apply`:

```
select i.*, t1.id
from inputs i outer apply
     (select top 1 t1.*
      from t1
      where (t1.Company = '*' or t1.Compay = i.Company) or
            (t1.Type = '*' or t1.Type = i.Type)
      order by ((case when t1.company = '*' then 0 else 1 end) +
                (case when t1.type = '*' then 0 else 1 end)
               ) desc
    ) t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM [test]
ORDER BY
        (CASE WHEN Company = @Company  and Type = @Type  THEN 1000 ELSE 0 END
        + CASE WHEN Company = @Company  and Type ='*' THEN 900 ELSE 1 END
        + CASE WHEN Company = '*' and Type = @Type  THEN 800 ELSE 2 END
        + CASE WHEN Company = '*' and Type = '*' THEN 700 ELSE 3 END
        ) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try bellow solution:

```
DECLARE @Company2Type TABLE (
    ID      INT NOT NULL 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
    Company VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Type]  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Company, [Type])     
)
INSERT  @Company2Type
VALUES  
(1, '*',    '*'),
(2, 'CMP1', '*'),
(3, 'CMP1', 'TYP1'),
(4, '*',    'TYP1'),
(5, '*',    'TYP2'),
(6, 'CMP1', 'TYP2');

DECLARE @TestData TABLE (
    Company VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Type]  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
INSERT  @TestData
VALUES  
('CMP1' , 'TYP1'),
('CMP2' , 'TYP2'),
('CMP5' , 'TYP5');

SELECT  *, COALESCE(rule1.ID, rule2.ID, rule3.ID, rule4.ID) AS [Output]
FROM    @TestData td
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  ct.ID
    FROM    @Company2Type ct
    WHERE   ct.Company = td.Company
    AND     ct.[Type] = td.[Type]
) rule1 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  ct.ID
    FROM    @Company2Type ct
    WHERE   rule1.ID IS NULL
    AND     ct.Company = td.Company
    AND     ct.[Type] = '*'
) rule2
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  ct.ID
    FROM    @Company2Type ct
    WHERE   rule1.ID IS NULL
    AND     ct.Company = '*'
    AND     ct.[Type] = td.[Type]
) rule3
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT  ct.ID
    FROM    @Company2Type ct
    WHERE   rule1.ID IS NULL
    AND     ct.Company = '*'
    AND     ct.[Type] = '*'
) rule4
```

Results:

```
Company Type ID   ID   ID   ID   Output
------- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ------
CMP1    TYP1 3    NULL NULL NULL 3
CMP2    TYP2 NULL NULL 5    1    5
CMP5    TYP5 NULL NULL NULL 1    1
```

Notes:

- [Rule1] Both companies and types match
- [Rule2] Companies match and test type matches *
- [Rule3] Test company matches * and types match
- [Rule4] Both companies and types match *